# Adding values to masked pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column at the end of the dataframe but the value varies according to the information in other two columns. The overall result should be a new column where the absolute values of another column have been re-scaled dividing the absolute value by the highest within the column

I tried to mask the dataframe but at the end of the for loop nothing happened to the overall df (i.e. when I ask for dr.head() there are no new columns)

```py
for n in list(top_dict.keys()):
    for c in clusters:
        mask=(data.season==n) & (data.cluster==c)
        for attribute in panel:
            ratio_list=[]
            for kpi in data[mask][attribute]:
                try:
                    ratio_list.append(kpi/top_dict[n][c][attribute]['Score'])
                except:
                    ratio_list.append(0)
            data[mask]['%s_ratio'%attribute]=ratio_list
```

after running the code, the old dataframe stays the same and no extra column are added.

Sample of data:

```
season  cluster val_1   val_2   val_3
2014    A         0       5      8
2016    B         1       7      0
2015    C         2       9      8
2015    C         3       3      9
2017    A         4       5      1
```

Comment: From your description, I don't understand why you need two columns: it appears you want to normalise the absolute values of a single column, which requires just one column as input. Could you 1/ describe the actual procedure you want to perform, and 2/ perhaps show a small input sample and a small expected output sample?

Comment: I have more or less this dataframe:
>season cluster val_1 val_2 val_3
>2014 A           0           5           8
>2016 B           1           7           0
>2015 C           2           9           8
>2015 C           3           3           9
>2017 A           4           5           1
The idea is to re-scale val1-2-3 according to the maximum within their cluster and their season (e.g. val-1 re-scaled for the maximum value of cluster A in year 2014 in the first row). I wanted to add the rows just to keep both absolute and relative values

Comment: Can you post an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Don't put valuable information in a comment: [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have seen this rather explicit warning:

> ```
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> ```

This means that `data[mask]` is just a slice on the original dataframe and should should not try to change elements from it but revert to the original dataframe with a global `loc`:

```
data.loc[mask, '%s_ratio'%attribute]=ratio_list
```

That should be enough to get rid of the warning and change the dataframe.